# "question the charges in my bill"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it grammatically correct to say "I also question the charges in my bill" or should it be "I also ask question about the charges in my bill"

Answer (score 1):

Your first alternative works and is idiomatic. The second alternative is incorrect.

Notice that “question” is being used as a verb not a noun in the first (correct) sentence. In the second (incorrect) sentence you seem to have two verbs of similar meaning side-by-side - “ask” and “question”.

Comment: With “ask a question” or “ask questions” it would be correct.